# Fitting a multinomial glm for a very large dataset

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, multinomial-distribution, multinomial-logit, nnet

I have compositional data where for two groups, where each is represented by two ages, there are 100 possible categories for which I observed counts:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("g1",200),rep("g2",200)),
                 age = c(rep("a1",100),rep("a2",100),rep("a1",100),rep("a2",100)),
                 category = rep(paste0("c",1:100),4),
                 n = c(rmultinom(1,7000,pgamma(shape=0.8,rate=0.1,q=seq(0.01,1,0.01))),
                       rmultinom(1,5000,pgamma(shape=0.8,rate=0.3,q=seq(0.01,1,0.01))),
                       rmultinom(1,1800,pgamma(shape=0.5,rate=0.1,q=seq(0.01,1,0.01))),
                       rmultinom(1,1200,pgamma(shape=0.9,rate=0.1,q=seq(0.01,1,0.01)))),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to fit a regression model to the multinomial counts as a response and estimate the `interaction effect` of the `category * group`, while controlling for `age`.

So far, I'm trying to use a `multicategorical` `glm` (with a `binomial(link = 'logit')`), to a `data.frame` where I transform the `df$n` (total counts) to a `binomial` (`binary`) form:

```
binomial.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$group),function(g){
  do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(dplyr::filter(df,group == g)$age),function(a){
    do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(dplyr::filter(df,group == g)$category),function(t){
      sum.non.category <- sum(dplyr::filter(df,group == g & age == a & category != t)$n)
      sum.category <- sum(dplyr::filter(df,group == g & age == a & category == t)$n)
      data.frame(group = g,age = a,category = t,assigned.category = c(rep(0,sum.non.category),rep(1,sum.category)))
    })) 
  }))
}))

binomial.df$group <- factor(binomial.df$group, levels = c("g1","g2"))
binomial.df$age <- factor(binomial.df$age, levels = c("a1","a2"))
binomial.df$category <- factor(binomial.df$category, levels = paste0("c",1:100))

mm.fit <- glm(assigned.category ~ category * group + age,data = binomial.df, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

Clearly for this size of data the `glm` call will run for days or even longer, so I'm looking for a more tractable way.

Any idea?

BTW, I tried using `nnet`'s `multinom` first:

```
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = c("g1","g2"))
df$age <- factor(df$age, levels = c("a1","a2"))
df$category <- factor(df$category, levels = paste0("c",1:100))
mm.fit <- nnet::multinom(n ~ category * group + age, data=df)
```

But I get:

```
Error in nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  : 
  too many (22220) weights
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. You seem to have two binary predictors, age and group. And also 100 multinomial responses, category. If this is the case, why not fit 100 separate models?

Comment: There is also the [biglm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html) R package. Though I'm not sure the *binomial.df* transformation makes sense.

Comment: Thank you @dipetkov. I tried to clarify my post. My data is compositional in the sense that for each combination of age and group, I observe a total of counts that are distributed across the 100 categories. What I'm trying to estimate os the effect of category * group on the counts as response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biglm::bigglm` fits the model in under five minutes on my computer

```
mm.fit1 <- bigglm(assigned.category ~ category * group + age,data = binomial.df, family = binomial(link = 'logit'),tolerance=1e-5, maxit=20, chunksize=50000)
```

```
> summary(mm.fit1)
Large data regression model: bigglm(assigned.category ~ category * group + age, data = binomial.df, 
    family = binomial(link = "logit"), tolerance = 1e-05, maxit = 20, 
    chunksize = 50000)
Sample size =  1500000 
                        Coef    (95%     CI)     SE      p
(Intercept)          -8.0060 -9.0063 -7.0058 0.5001 0.0000
categoryc2            0.6935 -0.5315  1.9185 0.6125 0.2576
categoryc3            1.1794  0.0356  2.3232 0.5719 0.0392
categoryc4            1.5052  0.3994  2.6111 0.5529 0.0065
categoryc5            1.4480  0.3363  2.5597 0.5559 0.0092
categoryc6            2.1126  1.0534  3.1718 0.5296 0.0001
categoryc7            2.1999  1.1455  3.2543 0.5272 0.0000
categoryc8            2.2274  1.1744  3.2804 0.5265 0.0000
categoryc9            2.1426  1.0851  3.2001 0.5288 0.0001
categoryc10           2.0171  0.9522  3.0820 0.5324 0.0002
    [snip]
categoryc91:groupg2   0.0738 -2.1856  2.3331 1.1297 0.9479
categoryc92:groupg2  -0.2208 -2.4864  2.0449 1.1328 0.8455
categoryc93:groupg2  -0.0685 -2.3308  2.1939 1.1312 0.9517
categoryc94:groupg2   0.1083 -2.1485  2.3651 1.1284 0.9235
categoryc95:groupg2  -0.2480 -2.5135  2.0175 1.1328 0.8267
categoryc96:groupg2   0.0391 -2.2188  2.2971 1.1290 0.9723
categoryc97:groupg2  -0.1088 -2.3670  2.1494 1.1291 0.9232
categoryc98:groupg2   0.2224 -2.0352  2.4801 1.1288 0.8438
categoryc99:groupg2  -0.0700 -2.3329  2.1929 1.1315 0.9507
categoryc100:groupg2 -0.3352 -2.5989  1.9285 1.1319 0.7671
```

I get essentially the same coefficients at 10 iterations, but with a message saying the fit hasn't converged (note that the `1e-5` tolerance is $10^{-5}$ standard errors, so fairly tight).